# Why might StringBuilder fail to AppendLine?

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have a problem concatenating strings in a C# / Unity app that I don't understand. This is a simple chat box that until today was working fine; I'm totally stumped as to why it has stopped working.

Code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
public void AddLine(string text)
{   
    builder.AppendLine(text);
    chatText.text = builder.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that the builder will take ONE input. It will append the text a single time. After that, no new text will be appended. The same is true if I don't use the stringbuilder class and just do **Chattext.text += '\n' + text;**

I can verify that the it is the string itself that is not being modified in any way. I have tried writing this a half dozen different ways. Why could this possibly be happening?

Comment: My guess is that your string contains a `\0` or something similar. This is *not* going to be about `StringBuilder`, but we can't really tell anything more without a [mcve].

Comment: Is chatText a multilne TextBox control with enough space to show more than one line?

Comment: Thank you Jon. I suspect there is something inside the string as well because I added a function like so:

`if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
        {
            AddLine("Input " + i.ToString());
            i++;
        }`

and that works correctly. The debug information for the incoming string seems perfect though; how can I drill down and get more info on that string?

Answer (score 1):

check if the multiline property of the ChatText is set to true

Comment: The text box is fine. I've also just added a little fuction to manually add text, and this DOES work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the bottom line is that the reason this failed to concatenate is because there was some hidden garbage in the input string. I don't know how it got there, but the solution was to use a Regular Expression to filter out invalid characters from the input string.

Comment: why did you delete the angular question